# How can I get the log-entries in my server.log file to print out on a jsf page

Tags: java, jsf, logging, jboss

I'm using jboss 7 and i have a server application with a db tier, a business tier and a web tier with some jsf pages. In my application i'm using the logger "org.slf4j.Logger" on different tiers to log some warning and errors to a log file.

My question is **how can I get the log-entries in my server.log file to print out on a jsf page**?

I don't want to read the file on ...jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log directly because my application may run on different platforms...

Answer (score 1):

Log into a database instead and serve the contents from there. No more relying on a specific directory (although you'll need a database).

Comment: I have thought that already, but writing to a log file with a logger is much more comfortable than to do id with a db... I think i first try to read the log file from my application...

Comment: It doesn't change the logging in your code, you just need an appender that will write to a database instead of a file.

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution but what worked for me which also includes some debug was:

```
String pathToJSF = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/");
System.out.println("Real Path is: " + pathToJSF);
String fileSeparator = File.separator;
System.out.println("JBoss log directory is: " + pathToJSF.substring(0, pathToJSF.indexOf("standalone" + fileSeparator) + ("standalone" + fileSeparator).length()) + "log" + fileSeparator);
String jbossLogFile = pathToJSF.substring(0, pathToJSF.indexOf("standalone" + fileSeparator) + ("standalone" + fileSeparator).length()) + "log" + fileSeparator + "server.log";
```

This worked on windows with the following debug output:

```
Real Path is: C:\jboss-eap-7.1.0_non_community\jboss-eap-7.1\standalone\deployments\My.ear\My.war
JBoss log directory is: C:\jboss-eap-7.1.0_non_community\jboss-eap-7.1\standalone\log\
```

Also of note, this only works with JBoss EAP 6 or greater as I'm specifying/looking for "standalone" which didn't exist in previous JBoss versions.  This may not be good to do it this way, but I did have a need to grab the servers log file and make it available and included in a downloadable zip file

Now reading the file and displaying it in the JSF page I leave up to you as I'm pretty sure you know how to do that!  This was also tested on linux